# Is there anyway to use lang attribute in <input type="date" >

Tags: html, datepicker, uidatepicker

I am developing project in japanese language.We are using HTML5 datepicker There is a requirement for datepicker to dispaly months,days in japanese language.Though I searched my level best, dint get any proper solution .

Can I use `<input type="date" lang='ja'>` to convert months and days of datepicker to display in japanese ?

Comment: Have you tried [`<input type="datetime-local" />`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local)?

Comment: Tried. Even it din't work.